# Surfaces with self intersection in 3-space

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, knot-theory

Let $F$ be a sphere in the Euclidean 3-space $\mathbb{R}^3$ With self intersection.  Let $C$ be a double point circle in $F$.  Then the double circle $C$ must bound a 2-disk in the standard sphere (sphere without self intersection). Suppose the surface is with non-zero genus, then in this case how can we describe $C$, of course it is no longer on the boundary of a 2-disk.

Comment: what is a double circle? or double point circle?

Comment: Two sheets intersect in a line, called a double line; if the intersection is a circle, then we call it a double circle. So we can visualize the two sheets as the following: one sheet is like a tube penetrating the other sheet.

Comment: If the surface is a sphere, then the tube is not a handle, this means the double circle bounds a disk on the tube, but if the surface is with non-zero genus then this handle might be equivalent to a handle attached.